# SSLCommerz-Laravel Payment gateway Pop Up page payment gateway method not come

Tags: laravel-10

[image]

I went try to get pop up page payment gateway list this page . But every time pop up page come and say sandbox.sslcommerz.com refused to connect . And console error give Refused to display 'https://sandbox.sslcommerz.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'. But i don't find any solution. Any give me a solution.

Advance Thanks.